# Error while running this simple codes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

i am learning the Python and try to create a program that calculate lunch expenses for a group of peoples. i found a simple "Hello World" Flask template and customize it by putting all my own code into template but cannot work. I just want to deploy and publish my little program and share to my friend to play it.

Below are the codes, does anyone know what is the problem? Many thanks in advance for your kind help:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route("/")

print("Welcome to the Shen Ho's Lunch Expenses Calculator!")
bill = float(input("What was the total bill? RM "))
tax = int(input("How much percent of service tax in the bill? "))
people = int(input("How many people to split the bill? "))


total_tax_amount = (bill * tax) / 100
total_bill = bill + total_tax_amount
bill_per_person = total_bill / people
final_amount = round(bill_per_person, 2)

print(f"Each person should pay: RM{final_amount}")
```

Comment: This isn't valid Python syntax. A [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) like `@app.route` must be applied to a function, and you're not declaring any functions in your code. I would suggest spending some time with some basic Python tutorials, or perhaps take a closer look at the [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/).

Comment: The use of `print()` and `input()` here suggests you are attempting to build a console app.  not a Flask app. Are you looking to build a web page or a console app?